# BigQuery: running last value and table join

Tags: google-bigquery

Table_1 is my Sales table:

```
Time | item | ...
-----------------
 1   |  X   | ...
 1   |  Y   | ...
 2   |  X   | ...
 4   |  X   | ...
 6   |  X   | ...
 6   |  Y   | ...
```

Table_2 is my Cost table

```
Time | item | Cost
-----------------
 1   |  X   | a
 1   |  Y   | b
 3   |  X   | c
 4   |  X   | d
 4   |  Y   | e
 5   |  X   | f
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:
**For each row in Table_1, get the latest Cost value from Table_2 (i.e. with at most, Table_1 row's Time)**

The result should look like this:

```
Time | item | ... | Cost
------------------------
 1   |  X   | ... | a
 1   |  Y   | ... | b
 2   |  X   | ... | a
 4   |  X   | ... | d
 6   |  X   | ... | f
 6   |  Y   | ... | e
```

(I know it's straight forward with traditional SQL using a subquery in the SELECT section or unequal joins, but BigQuery doesn't allow it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
SELECT sales.time AS [time], sales.item AS item, cost 
FROM (
  SELECT sales.item, sales.time, cost, 
         cost.time - sales.time AS delta,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sales.item, sales.time ORDER BY delta DESC) AS win
  FROM Table_1 as sales
  LEFT JOIN Table_2 as cost
  ON sales.item = cost.item
  WHERE cost.time - sales.time <= 0
) 
WHERE win = 1
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Should give you exactly result you expect

```
time    item    cost     
   1       x       a     
   1       y       b     
   2       x       a     
   4       x       d     
   6       x       f     
   6       y       e
```

Comment: thanks so much! (and BTW, that "<1" was bugging me but you fixed it!)

Comment: yes. i realized this last night that "<1" is perfectly OK for this particular dummy example, but in real example it actually must be "<=0" so I edited it for you